# MySQL query based on 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I work with PHP. I have a table named books. In table books I have the `book_name` with the name of the book, `book_publisher` with the publisher's ID and `book_author` with the author's ID. Besides the books table I have the `books_author` table with the authors names and IDs and `books_publisher` with the books publishers names and IDs.

I give my users 3 input fields that represents author name, book name and publisher name and a search button. They can input an author name, a book name and publisher name in the same search and I have to query my database and return the books names that have author name LIKE (%..%) inputted author name, book name LIKE the inputted book name and publisher name LIKE the inputted publisher name.

The problem is that I have stored only the author's id and publisher's id in my books table and I need to search by all three fields and exclude duplicates (books that were match by name and also by publisher).

Can anybody help me building this query ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just join the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM books b
JOIN book_authors ba ON b.author_id = ba.id
JOIN book_publishers bp ON b.publisher_id = bp.id
WHERE b.book_name LIKE '...'
AND ba.author_name LIKE '...'
AND bp.publisher_name LIKE '...'
```

Usually in these situations the search boxes are optional so you'll need to dynamically construct the query, meaning the `WHERE` clause to only filter on, say, publisher name if the user actually entered a publisher name.

Also, searching on `LIKE '%blah%'` is not scalable beyond thousands or possibly tens of thousands of records. No indexing can cater for that. You may want to look into using something like the [MySQL full-text searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead.

Lastly, make sure you sanitize your input, meaning pass all your input fields through [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://au.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Comment: Even better is indexing the text fields with Sphinx Search.  I understand it's a lot faster than MySQL's built-in full-text indexing, supports stemming, etc.